# Dynamic PHP Array used in sendmany bitcoin command issue

Tags: bitcoind, php

I have following problem with dynamic array be used in sendmany transaction in bitcoin engine, problem described in code comments.

step 1 create array
step 2 inserting values to array
step 3 print an array to check the result which is correct
step 4 sendmany (here is a problem) see below

```
<?php
//step 1 create array
$to = array();
//step 2 inserting values to array
while ( $row_users = mysqli_fetch_array($getting_allowed_users) )
{
          $to[] = array($row_users['user_bitcoin_wallet'] => $currency);
}

//step 3 print an array to check the result which is correct
print_r(array_values($to)); 

//step 4 sendmany (here is a problem)

// if I do it that way sendmany is only sending to first wallet which is indexed [0]
// I cannot to foreach as php  code structure is not allowing {} inside the command
$bitcoin->sendmany($BuyerAccount,$to[0]); 

//Question: How I can display all the values from my array in following place
$bitcoin->sendmany($BuyerAccount,ALL THE VALUES); 

//example
$bitcoin->sendmany($BuyerAccount,"walet1"=>0.1,"walet2"=>0.1,"walet3"=>0.1.....);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:
`$bitcoin -> sendmany($BuyerAccount, $to);`?
Bitcoin API states `<fromaccount> {address:amount,...} [minconf=1] [comment]` as parameters, so you don't have to iterate - pass the whole array.
If it doesn't work somehow, you can also prepare request by yourself for RPCClient. This is example for sendfrom:
                `$request = '{"method":"sendfrom","params":["'.$params[0].'","'.$params[1].'",'.$params[2].','.$params[3].'],"id":'.$currentId.'}';`

Comment: thank you, array is dynamic and if passed to looks like: array{array{"element1"=>1,"element2"=>1....}} what we need just that middle part "element1"=>1,"element2"=>1 and we cannot call it by number of item from array as we don't know how many we may have.... what it works is $to[0] or $to[1] ..etc on it's own...

Answer (score 0):

I am actually working on trying to figure out the same thing, but from my understanding is you are looking to have it repeat? Try something like this.

```
$to = array();
$count = 0;

while ( $row_users = mysqli_fetch_array($getting_allowed_users) )
{
          $to[$count++] = array($row_users['user_bitcoin_wallet'] => $currency);
}
```